# Presenting Modal View Controller in iOS not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I need to show another view from rootviewcontroller on button click. I have written the following code but it doesnt work. Any ideas why?

In my app delegate method i have the following code -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Then in my mainviewcontroller i have a button action which is supposed to take me to a different class but it does nothing. Although the button action is working since nslog statements work. Any ideas?

```
   LoginViewController * loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.modalViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
NSLog(@"HE::P");
```

Comment: What is this `modalViewController` property? Shouldn't it be `[self presentModalViewController...]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try :

```
[self presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
```